# SQL Server With CTE variable not accepting

Tags: sql, sql-server

With CTE if i assign the variable outside and call the varibale inside the table not accepting the variable but if i pass the value directly inside the CTE query return the value.

```
DECLARE @dates datetime = '8/5/2019 12:41:55 PM',
        @Staff nvarchar(250) = N'staff1';
WITH
CTE AS
    (SELECT DI.SchedulerID,
            DI.CustID,
            ORC.CustomerName,
            (SELECT CONVERT(char(5), DI.InTime, 108) AS [time]) AS InTime,
            DI.Identifier,
            DI.PictureUploaded,
            (SELECT CONVERT(char(5), DO.OutTime, 108) AS [time]) AS OutTime,
            CONCAT((DATEDIFF(MINUTE, DI.InTime, DO.OutTime) / 60), ':', (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, DI.InTime, DO.OutTime) % 60)) AS SpendInMinutes,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DI.SchedulerID,
                                            ORC.CustomerName
                               ORDER BY DI.SchedulerID DESC) AS RN
     FROM [ServiceUsers].[dbo].[DeliveryIn] DI
          INNER JOIN [Distribution].dbo.ORCustomerList ORC ON DI.CustID = ORC.CustID
          INNER JOIN [ServiceUsers].[dbo].[DeliveryOut] DO ON DI.SchedulerID = DO.SchedulerID
     WHERE (SELECT CONVERT(date, DI.InDate)) = (SELECT @dates)
       AND DI.CreatedBy = (SELECT @Staff))
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

If i pass the values directly to the where it will return the rows.

Comment: show us how you call it when you pass in the variable

Comment: If you `CAST` the value of `DI.InDate` to a `date`, how can it ever have the `datetime` value `'2019-05-08T12:41:55'`? `CONVERT(date,'2019-05-08T12:41:55') = CONVERT(datetime,''2019-05-08T12:41:55')` returns `FALSE`.

Answer (score 2):

**Note to commenters -- I'm not saying the code is "wrong" and would not run, just that it is strange and not the typical way it would be written**

your sql is strange

```
Where (SELECT CONVERT(date, DI.InDate))=(Select @dates) AND DI.CreatedBy=(Select @Staff)
```

should be

```
Where CONVERT(date, DI.InDate)=@dates AND DI.CreatedBy=@Staff
```

also I would write declare like this

```
DECLARE @dates datetime;
DECLARE @staff nvarchar(250);

SET @dates='2019-08-05';
SET @Staff=N'staff1';
```

Comment: That `WHERE` makes no sense. The OP set's the value of `@dates` to be `'8/5/2019 12:41:55 PM'`. No value cast to a `date` can ever be that value. I realise that's what they have in their query, but that doesn't change the fact that it's simply not right. :/

Comment: `CONVERT(date, DI.InDate)=(select @dates)` should work too.

Comment: And the declaration of both variables in a single DECLARE statement is also valid.

Comment: The declaration of both variables in a single DECLARE statement **strange** and **not the typical** way? Since when?

Comment: @forpas -- I don't believe it is standard sql.

Comment: @Hogan https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#b-using-declare-with-two-variables

Comment: @forpas -- that is sql server, not oracle, db2, progresql, etc.

Comment: The question is tagged SQL Server.

Comment: @forpas - and I was answering in a way that worked with SQL server *and* the maximum number of other platforms.  Since (IMHO) that is the best way to answer questions on this web site.  Feel free to vote me down or up as you wish

Comment: The OP's problem is not to improve the code but *why this code does not work*. Your *answer* does not answer the question (nor improves anything).

Comment: @Hogan i am not an expert like you. surely you have more ideas to solve the issues. i want to generate some extra report from the database only. come to your point InDate is converting because i need the full day report if i pass without converting only date it will check with date & time. that is my code and what i tried it is return the rows also. but why i cant pass the value from outside the CTE that is my doubt. i am poor in english hope you understand.

Comment: @NAJEEB -- you really don't give enough detail to answer -- you don't show an example of "passing outside" which I **specifically** asked for in the comments above -- but it is probably just that you are not formatting the date string correctly and it can't parse it.